# Is it unethical to take ideas from a pre-print to write your own research paper (though the author of the pre-print is acknowledged)?

Tags: publications, ethics

One of my friends is in a very curious position. He has been researching on a number theoretic problem for months but couldn’t solve it until recently after he has seen a pre-print in arXiv which attempts to prove the problem. But though he has taken ideas from the pre-print, his own article differs considerably from that of the pre-print. According to him, following are the chief points of difference,

1. My friend actually proved a stronger version of the problem.
2. He gave an outline to the proof of a conjecture that the author of the pre-print stated in the concluding section of his/her paper.

My friend has decided to mention precisely how much he had been benefited from the paper in the **Acknowledgements** section. Will there be any problem if he sends his article to a journal for publication?

Comment: Isn't this how it's supposed to work? People get ideas from reading papers, extend the previous work, give due credit?

Comment: I would mention that in my field (theoretical particle physics), this is a very _common_ position to be in. Definitely not one I would describe as "curious".

Comment: As an anonymous user on an internet forum, it is _okay_ to use _I_ instead of _my friend_ all the time. We've all had these _friends_!

Comment: @TheDarkSide I guess the anonymity is what enabled the OP to say the person in question is a friend, as opposed to the more usual friend of a friend.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

He should just cite what he used or learned from the ArXiv paper and send it in. There's no real need to add an acknowledgement.

Comment: Even if it is not a published paper?

Comment: @user170039: Yes, the same citations are appropriate and required, regardless of whether the paper is published or not (but there is no need for extra acknowledgement beyond what would be used for the published paper).

Comment: I agree. Given the fast moving nature of the field, in a case like this I'd advise specifically noting and including the retrieval date in the citations. Many journals ask for this, in any case.

Comment: He should also consider sending a copy of the paper to the author of that preprint.

Comment: @user170039, yes, it's published, and he should cite it with as much specificity as he can. It's not published in a peer-review journal, so there could be some who think of the source as unreliable and non-archival. It seems like mathematics is one area where this is less of a concern.

Comment: @user170039 It *is* published in the literal sense of "made public", but not in the more restricted sense of "disseminated by a publishing organization."

Comment: He should *cite* the ArXiv paper, and not just mention it in acknowledgements.

Comment: @ScottSeidman, isn't that what my answer says?

Comment: @MarkJoshi: For an arXiv preprint the retrieval date isn't really relevant; what you want is the arXiv id and version number.  Any change to an arXiv preprint bumps the version number, and all past versions are permanently archived and cannot be modified.  (Of course, it's possible that some journal wants you to include retrieval date anyway, and you might as well humor them, but the version number is what you really need.)

Comment: Furthermore to what Nate Eldredge says, *the retrieval date does not tell you which version of the paper was retrieved*. I'm not actually aware of a convention in my field (not math) to cite arXiv version numbers, but come to think of it, it really should be done.

Answer (score 21):

@BillBarth has the correct approach, but his phrasing "just cite", and "no real need for an acknowledgement" I find rather misleading, because it seems that the attribution is being somehow reduced.

The reality is that this preprint should be referenced and cited **in the main body of the paper, where its contribution is used**, and not merely mentioned in the acknowledgements where few readers will actually note it.

Comment: Bill's answer is surely short, but I can't see how it can be considered misleading.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment on Bill's answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @espertus: This certainly does provide an answer to the question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: False.  It is a complete answer.  I have also explained how it relates to the earlier answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt You're technically right, but the number of negative comments should guide you to think of how to improve your answer.  As a reviewer (which is where I saw your answer), I recommend moving the first paragraph into a comment and adding a bit to the beginning of the remaining second paragraph.

Comment: You could just edit @BillBarth's answer instead, resorting to post your own only if the edit is refused.

Comment: @Lohoris: That would not be an appropriate edit (or edit suggestion).

Comment: @BenVoigt of course it would be

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned in other answers, it's completely fine to use / extend ideas from a preprint that's been posted on arXiv or otherwise made public.  This is essentially the exact reason why the author made the preprint public in the first place.  You will cite the preprint as you would a paper published in a journal, conference proceedings, etc, except that of course you will list an arXiv ID instead of a journal title, volume number, etc.  Your journal's style guide should explain how to cite preprints (if using BiBTeX, consider `@preprint`).

You may convey additional thanks in your Acknowledgements section if you are moved to do so, but this should not take the place of proper citation.

Of course, as is the case whenever you are extending someone else's work, your paper should accurately describe the work done by the preprint's author, and carefully distinguish it from what you have added.  You should be careful that you do not inadvertently misrepresent the preprint author's work as your own.

There are a few extra considerations when extending work from a preprint:

- Keep in mind that the preprint has not undergone peer review.  Of course, peer review is no guarantee of correctness, and if you are writing a paper that depends heavily on a previous paper, you will want to check it carefully enough to be sure that your work rests on solid foundations, regardless of where/if the previous paper was published.  But for an unreviewed preprint, you should check it even more carefully.
- Before starting work on your own paper, you might want to consider contacting the preprint author with your idea and suggesting a collaboration.  In addition to sharing expertise, this also helps mitigate the risk that the preprint author has already had an idea similar to yours, and is currently writing it up in a paper that will be published before yours would be.  (This is also possible when extending work from a traditionally published paper, but is perhaps somewhat more likely in the preprint case because of the shorter timeline; if the work is very recent, it's more likely that the author is still actively working on related topics.)
- There's a good chance that the preprint is currently being reviewed for traditional publication.  Before submitting your paper, you should check to see whether the preprint has been accepted / published in a journal / proceedings / etc, and update your citation if necessary.  (If it has been accepted but not yet published, you can list it as "To appear" with the journal's title.)  Check one more time when you correct the galley proofs of your paper.
- Check periodically to see if the preprint has been revised or updated, as the changes may involve something that materially affects your paper.  Note that arXiv only includes the first 5 updates in their daily emails, so just checking the emails may not suffice.  It is even possible for an arXiv preprint to be withdrawn by the author (this might happen if they find a fundamental error); it remains available for download, but in this case it's probably not a good idea to try to use it.  (Of course, published papers can also have corrigenda or retractions, but they are more common for preprints.)

Answer (score -2):

No,there is nothing unethical to take ideas from a pre-print to write your own research paper,especially if the author of the pre-print is already acknowledged in your paper,

Comment: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/46879/is-it-unethical-to-take-ideas-from-a-pre-print-to-write-your-own-research-paper/46957#

Comment: What does this add to the existing answers?

Comment: Are you advocating for only citing one work from any given author, no matter how many of their papers actually developed work you used?